# Поддержка конфигурации бинов в groovy-конфигах со стороны Intellij idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, groovy

В Spring 4 есть [возможность конфигурировать бины через Groovy-конфиг](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4). Я определяю бин также, как сделал бы это в XML, используя груви-DSL, груви конфиг лежит в ресурсах:

```
beans {
    logReader(FileLogReader)
}
```

Затем импортирую его в основной Java-конфиг через аннотацию `@ImportResource`.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:beansconfig.groovy"})
```

Но Idea не понимает, что эти бины есть в контексте, когда я пытаюсь привязать их через @Autowired (среда выводит подсказку `Could not autowire`, поскольку не видит бина с таким именем).

[image: Could not autowire]

Само приложение запускается без проблем. Как настроить проект так, чтобы idea распознавала Groovy-конфиги или она вообще не понимает такой метод определения бинов? И насколько вообще распространен данный метод? Видел на YouTube доклады, в которых говорить, что Groovy-конфиги совмещают в себе гибкость Java-конфигураций и возможность их менять без перекомпиляции (как XML-конфиги). Однако на видел, чтобы много кто использовал данный метод конфигурации, вдобавок и среда не очень его поддерживает (возможно, я делаю что-то не так).

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю, для чего Вам в `java config` тянуть бины, которые описаны в виде `groovy config`.

Если хотите использовать `groovy config`, то используйте сразу контекст `GenericGroovyApplicationContext`.